# Can I use OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier with react-google-maps?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-maps, react-google-maps, markerspiderfier

I'm working on a project which uses `react-google-maps` (https://github.com/tomchentw/react-google-maps) library.

It works well, but we stumbled upon a problem with overlapping markers. Ideal solution to our case would be to use this plugin: https://github.com/jawj/OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier.

Is there any way to use it with `react-google-maps`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How to [`OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier` plugin](https://github.com/jawj/OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier) integrate into [`react-google-maps`](https://github.com/tomchentw/react-google-maps)

1)install `npm-overlapping-marker-spiderfier` package: `npm i npm-overlapping-marker-spiderfier`

2) once installed the following component demonstrates how to create the instance of OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier class and pass markers:

```
import React from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { MAP, MARKER } from "react-google-maps/lib/constants";


class Spiderfy extends React.Component {
  static contextTypes = {
    [MAP]: PropTypes.object
  };

  constructor(props, context) {
    super(props, context);
    const oms = require(`npm-overlapping-marker-spiderfier/lib/oms.min`)
    this.oms = new oms.OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier(this.context[MAP], {});
    this.markerNodeMounted = this.markerNodeMounted.bind(this);
  }

  markerNodeMounted(ref) {
    const marker = ref.state[MARKER];
    this.oms.addMarker(marker); 
    window.google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "spider_click", (e) => {
      if (this.props.onSpiderClick) this.props.onSpiderClick(e);
    });
  }

  render() {
    return React.Children.map(this.props.children, child =>
      React.cloneElement(child, { ref: this.markerNodeMounted })
    );
  }
}
```

**Usage**

```
<GoogleMap
  defaultZoom={zoom}
  defaultCenter={{
    lat: center.lat,
    lng: center.lng
  }}
>
  <Spiderfy>
    <Marker
      position={{
        lat: center.lat,
        lng: center.lng
      }}
    />
    <Marker
      position={{ lat: -37.9716929, lng: 144.772958 }}
      title="Melbourne"
    />
    <Marker
      position={{ lat: -38.132245, lng: 144.2994245 }}
      title="Geelong"
    />
    <Marker
      position={{ lat: -38.2277575, lng: 145.0447435 }}
      title="Mornington"
    />
  </Spiderfy>
</GoogleMap>
```

[Here is a demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ns6qdu) for your reference

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! I'll check it out tomorow :)

Comment: Thanks for this. Will this work with custom react components instead of default google map markers?

Comment: Some  adjustment might be needed, in the provided implementation there's a dependency to marker native object which is passed via context

Comment: The demo appears to be broken (not just the expired key) - markers do not have spiderfy icon and app crashes when icon clicked. Anyone have a working react-google-maps / react code example they can share?